# How to graph the all of the possible isomorphic graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

We can get one form of it use `Graph`

```
Graph[{1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 5, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 4, 2 <-> 5}, 
 VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

But how to graph the all form of its isomorphic graph?As I know this is one of it.

[image]

Update:

For example:

```
Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1, 2 <-> 4, 3 <-> 5, 5 <-> 6, 6 <-> 7, 
  7 <-> 5, 8 <-> 4, 1 <-> 5, 3 <-> 7, 1 <-> 8, 3 <-> 8, 4 <-> 7}, 
 VertexLabels -> "Name", GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"]
```

[image]

But the following graph is expected

[image]

I just wanna move the number 8 and number 4.Thanks @Chip Hurst for your `Options` of `VertexCoordinates`.It should be get the result.But setting every vertex's coordinate is too troublesome I think,and the `Option` `GraphLayout` have not this value.

Comment: Would adding the option `GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding"` suffice, or do you want the graph rotated too?

Comment: @ChipHurst Yeah,thanks.The `GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding"` can get the graph I have illustrated.But can graph all of it?

Comment: What do you mean by "how to graph all forms"?  There are infinitely many ways to draw it.  Do you mean all labellings of vertices?  You can generate all permutations of the vertex indices.

Comment: Check out GraphData, and look for embeddings

Comment: You can also manually place vertices anywhere with the option `VertexCoordinates`.

Comment: @ChipHurst I update the question to specify it.Can you give another promption?

Comment: @M.R. Thanks for your pay attention to this question and I update it just now to specify it.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you very much,and sorry for my poor ability of expression to mislead you.I update a example to depict what I want just now.If you can give another help,I will appreciate you.

Comment: for the example in your update you can use `edges = {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1, 2 <-> 4, 3 <-> 5, 5 <-> 6, 
   6 <-> 7, 7 <-> 5, 8 <-> 4, 1 <-> 5, 3 <-> 7, 1 <-> 8, 3 <-> 8, 
   4 <-> 7};
vertices = {2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 8, 7, 6}; Graph[vertices, edges, 
 VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", 
   "VertexPartition" -> {1, 3, 3, 1}}, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> {(3 <-> 1) -> 
    GraphElementData[{"CurvedArc", "Curvature" -> 1/2}], (7 <-> 5) -> 
    GraphElementData[{"CurvedArc", "Curvature" -> -1/2}]} , 
 ImagePadding -> 10]`.

Comment: @If I just want a rotated graph,how can I realize it simply?

Comment: Sorry, I think I do not understand your question.  Is it a certain layout that you need to get (i.e. certain vertex coordinates)?  If yes, is there something special about the layout that you are showing that would allow Mathematica to produce it automatically?  Otherwise I think the only options you have are: 1. write the vertex coordinates manually, or 2. try all built in layouts to see if there's one you like

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks all the same.